# How to: if image exists on server return image else return my own image?

Tags: php, json, image

I can't find out how to achieve this and i struggle whole morning to get it somehow but i can't.

I pull some data from steam from their steam api service in json file, but problem is i don't know if they did this on purpose or just assumed that people won't use their api so they posted a link to an image in json file but actual image on server don't exists, even if i visit their website for that package i pulled from json file image doesn't exists even on their website.

So i was wondering how do i override this?

When i pull json file the array returns this (it's just part where image is, actual json file is extremely large to copy it here)

```
            [name] => Enclave
                [page_image] => http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/subs/31131/header.jpg?t=1380891628
                [apps] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 253980
                                [name] => Enclave
                            )

                    )
```

So if you visit a website for that game image doesn't exists, if you follow image link

```
http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/subs/31131/header.jpg?t=1380891628
```

it returns 404 error file not exists.

So in cases where image doesn't exists how do i override this and show my own image?

I tried with

```
if(!empty($image))
if(property_exists($image))
if($image !== false)

and of course $image path to json data [page_image]
```

none of combination works

However when image exists it shows me the image properly so $image is set properly.

Any idea how do i override this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) is a way to check if a resource actually is an image. `getimagesize` returns an array, **if** the link points to a valid image resource. You can use `getimagesize` on remote files also :

```php
$image = 'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/subs/31131/header.jpg?t=1380891628';

if (is_array(@getimagesize($image))) {
   //image exists
} else {
   //image does not exists
}
```

---

Instead of suppressing `getimagesize` warnings by `@`, change the level of error reporting in runtime, before the call :

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
```

you can switch back and forth so `E_WARNING`'s still will be echoed in the rest of your application.

Comment: This works, but any other way to fix an error rather than suppressing  it?

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević, yes, `@` was just my laziness. See update. Of course `@` should be avoided.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, although i will rather use @ than changing error_reporting. But anyway i noticed getimagesize is rather slow function. When there are for example 5 or more images to get, the website takes more than 10 seconds to load.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević, change error_reporting before and after the call to getimagesize, so it is just getimagesize's E_WARNING you suppress. getimagesize should never be _that_ slow, used it myself with 100's of remote images. Maybe the servers or the connection is slow? However, I would use a lookuplist. A simple list of images already checked. Either as an array on the session, or as a ini-based text file where you append checked image paths and their status. Both solutions would certainly speed up your application. Alternative, use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this from PHP, then you may:

```
$fh = @fopen($image, 'r');
$imageexists = $fh!=false;
if ($fh) fclose($fh);
```